# Using a module Globally -Making it sure it doesn't recreating multiple instance

Tags: nestjs

I've created a Global NestJs Module for a Slack Integration.
my Slack Module

```
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SlackService } from 'src/services/common/slack.service';
import { SlackController } from 'src/controllers/common/slack.controller';

    @Global()
    @Module({
        imports: [SlackModule],
        providers: [SlackService],
        controllers: [SlackController],
        exports: [SlackService]
    })
    export class SlackModule {}
```

My SlackService

```
      @Injectable()
      export class SlackService {
       constructor(
        @Inject(WINSTON_MODULE_PROVIDER) private readonly logger: Logger,
        private configService: ConfigService
    ) {}

    private ENABLE_SLACK_NOTIFICATIONS = this.configService.get<string>('ENABLE_SLACK_NOTIFICATION') === 'true';
    private SLACK_ENG_INTERNAL_URL = this.configService.get<string>('SLACK_ENG_INTERNAL_URL');
    private SLACK_ENG_INTERNAL_WEBHOOK = new IncomingWebhook(this.SLACK_ENG_INTERNAL_URL);

...
```

I want to make sure my understanding is correct that this will make only one WebHook that will be used throughout the app rather than one for every time I used it in other services.

Should I remove `private` from:
`private SLACK_ENG_INTERNAL_WEBHOOK = new IncomingWebhook(this.SLACK_ENG_INTERNAL_URL);`

Answer (score 1):

So long as you don't add `SlackService` to any other `providers` arrays, there will be only one instance of the provider, and thus, the `IncomingWebhook` you create